# How does one extract audio from a video (DVD movie) using Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, dvd, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to get audio from home DVDs?](https://superuser.com/questions/2837/software-to-get-audio-from-home-dvds)

I have a DVD movie from which I would like to extract the audio, preferably to MP3, so I can listen to it -- it's an interview video, and the picture is largely superfluous.  I've seen some responses here on how to do this with OSX and Linux and Bash, etc, but not Windows.

I have Win Vista, and while I am certain there has to be some application out there that can do this, I am unaware of it.

Comment: Turns out this has already been answered. Hopefully the answers in the duplicate question work for you; if not, you can edit this question to include what you tried from the other question that didn't work, and we'll reopen it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Free Video to MP3 Converter](http://www.dvdvideosoft.com/guides/free-video-to-mp3-converter.htm).  Instructions can be found on the link above.

If you want something a little bit more sophisticated, you can follow the directions on [make use of](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extract-your-concert-dvd-audio-to-mp3-with-4-simple-tools/).

If you require any further assistance, just post a comment.

Comment: I installed it and it is a useful program, but it doesn't seem to extract DVD movies; it is for taking things like *.MP4 and other video files and extracting the audio.  If I wanted to extract the audio portion of, say, a copy of Gone With The Wind on DVD (not what I am trying to extract it from, btw), Free Video to MP3 Converter doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: What is the file format of the video file in question?  (Click explore on the DVD in My Computer).  Also, did you use [Smart Ripper](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/SmartRipper) from the [make use of](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extract-your-concert-dvd-audio-to-mp3-with-4-simple-tools/) article?